# Symbols of mercy in Buddhism?

Tags: iconography

What are the possible symbols of mercy and/or compassion in Buddhism? As always answers with supporting references are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [8 auspicious symbols](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/history/b8symbol.htm),

The
Auspicious Drawing, sometimes refereed to as the [infinite knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_knot) 
represents the intertwining of wisdom and compassion.

[image]

The [manji](http://symboldictionary.net/?p=1669) (Japanese Buddhism) is said to represent love and mercy, in certain situations. 
This symbol should not be confused with the [swastika](http://www.religie.eu/SLANG-occultisme/4.7art.Swastica/2.ancient-symbol/2.ancient-symbol.htm), which is completely different.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The right hand of [this statue](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13465/254) shows the [Varada Mudrā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudra#Varada_Mudr.C4.81) which represents generosity and compassion.

Comment: Nice, can't believe I forgot to look for mudras