# What is a nirvana?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, nirvana

I think the title says it all.I know that an enlightened person's soul will go to nirvana after their death, but what is really nirvana? 
Is it some kind of a place or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you tagged the question 'tibetan-buddhism', is that because you want answers that are from the perspective of specifically-Tibetan Buddhism, and explicitly not from the perspective of e.g. Theravada Buddhism?

Comment: I really doubt it is somethings that can be defined explicitly. It is easier to say what it not than to say what it is. I was taught by a monk that the one of the greatest lies that we can say is to define nirvana wrongly. According to him it cannot be defined

Comment: I have written an answer [here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/what-does-deathless-mean/10927#10927) where the Buddha describes Nibbana. Maybe it will be of use for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's definitely not a place, it's a no-place

this question could gave been answered earlier, please review

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+nirvana

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+nibbana

please also refer to

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca3/nibbana.html
http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/nibbana.html

Answer (score 3):

Nirvana is the cessation of the cause (attachment, hatred, delusion, non attachment, non hatred, non delusion) of continuous existance. With cessation of the cause perception and sensations cesses. The implication of perception cessing is of perception is you do not analyse any experience as good, bad or neutral and sensation cessing means the whole sphere of unsatisfactoriness cesses.